# scala implicit convertion and arrow

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm struggling with my DSL building attempt

My method should take multiple pairs of (A, B), ideally I'm looking for this kind of code:

```
myMethod(
  a1 -> b1,
  a2 -> b2,
  a3 -> b3)
```

my A and B classes happened to often be constructed with a single string parameter, so i added implicit converters looking like this:

```
implict def stringToA(s: String): A = new A(s)
implict def stringToB(s: String): B = new B(s)
```

but arrow operator(for pair construction) doesn't pick up implicit converters:

```
object Test {
  case class A(s: String)
  case class B(s: String)

  def myMethod(pairs: (A, B)*): Unit = Unit

  implicit def stringToA(s: String): A = A(s)
  implicit def stringToB(s: String): B = B(s)

  myMethod(new Tuple2("a", "b")) // works just fine
  myMethod("a" -> "b") // Error: Type mismatch, expected: (Test.A, Test.B), actual: (String, String)
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `->` method is made available on all Scala types by an implicit conversion (`any2ArrowAssoc` in `scala.Predef`). For reasons of sanity, Scala doesn't allow multiple implicit conversions to "chain" on the same expression. You could:

- Define an explicit `->` method on your `A` class. Unfortunately since the default implicit conversion would conflict with this you might then have to build your code with `-Yno-predef` to avoid the conflict
- Define a method on your `A` class with a visually similar name that doesn't conflict, e.g. `~>` or `»`
- Call `myMethod(("a", "b"))` if you like that syntax (this syntax is supported directly, not via an implicit conversion)
- Make `myMethod` accept `(String, String)*` and do the conversion to `A` and `B` inside.
- Edit: You could also define an implicit conversion from `(String, String)` to `(A, B)` as @BenReich suggests.

Comment: "Unfortunately since the default implicit conversion would conflict with this you might then have to build your code with -Yno-predef to avoid the conflict" No, if there is an explicit `->` method, the implicit conversion won't be tried.

Comment: There's no explicit `->` on String, so the implicit conversion to `A` and the one to `Any2ArrowAssoc` both offer a `->` method and they would I think conflict.

Comment: Ah, yes, if `A` is obtained by an implicit conversion, there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an implicit conversion from (String, String) to (A, B):

```
implicit def toABTuple(in: (String, String)) = (A(in._1), B(in._2))
```

It's failing because its converting to a tuple before applying your implicits, so it's not a plain String -> A/B anymore.